# how to use iframe tag overlapping a <dl>

Tags: html

I have created some definition lists in `html` .And I want to set an image using `iframe` tag that overlaps the dl.
Then how to set particular area for `iframe` tag no matter whether there is any other element occupying that area? I want overlapping. Please help.

Comment: Show us your code. And why would you want to use an iframe for a single image?

Comment: can't we use iframe for a single image?

Comment: Well, I guess if you really want to nobody's going to stop you, but why would you want to do that? Why not use an image tag?

Comment: You must read this first - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @René Roth ....as I asked I want to overlap definition list.Will Image tag fulfill my purpose?

Comment: Of course you can set an image tag to overlay any other element if you position it that way.

Comment: Will you please tell me that way?

Comment: `position:relative` and `z-index` is what you will need

Comment: and one more thing.Why you guys downvote to a post?As I am a new user I dint get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated i my comment, you need to use `position:relative` and `z-index` on the image and then you can use css to move the image where you want over the `<dl>`

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/22QqQ/)

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    top:70px;
    left:30px;
}
```